# Query on my data datastore that mixes a filter StContainsFilter and FilterPredicate

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-datastore

Sorry for my English.

I'm working on an android application that stores data on the Datastore Google cloud. I want to carry out a query on my datastore that mixes `StContainsFilter` and `FilterPredicate`. It does not work! Here is my code:

```
DatastoreService service = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("utilisateurs");
Query.Filter filtrage1 = new Query.FilterPredicate("sexe", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, "M");

Query.Filter filtrage2 = new Query.FilterPredicate("datenaissance", Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, datemin);
Query.Filter filtrage3 = new Query.FilterPredicate("datenaissance", Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, datemax);

GeoPt center = new GeoPt(Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lng));
double radius = km*1000;
Query.Filter filtrage4 = new Query.StContainsFilter("location", new GeoRegion.Circle(center, radius));
Query.Filter present = Query.CompositeFilterOperator.and(filtrage2,filtrage3,filtrage1,filtrage4);
q.setFilter(present);
PreparedQuery pq = service.prepare(q);
List<Entity> results = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Answer (score 0):

To mix different filters you can use a [CompositeFilter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.CompositeFilter). You can read more about Datastore Queries [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/queries). With the CompositeFilter, you can connect multiple Filters, which then act as one. However, you still have to consider not to set inequality Filters on more than one property.

To create a CompositeFilter use this syntax:

```
CompositeFilter nameOfFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(Collection<Filter>);
```

Collection can also be a List, an Array or you can seperate Filters by comma

Here an example on how to create a CompositeFilter:

```
Filter filter1 = new FilterPredicate("someProperty", FilterOperator.Equal, someValue)
Filter filtrage4 = new StContainsFilter("location", new GeoRegion.Circle(center, radius));
Filter filtrage2 = new FilterPredicate("datenaissance", Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, datemin);

CompositeFilter filter = CompositeFilterOperator.or(filter1, filtrage4, filtrage2);
```

Use CompositeFilterOperator.and if you need all Filters to apply and .or if one applying Filter is enough.

Technically your solution should work because StContainsFilter is a direct subclass from Query.Filter. The reason for your problem is a wrong import. You should check your imports and change them if they say anything with "repackaged" (I hade the same problem too)